# What does monkey and eagle/pigeon signify here?

Tags: temple, identification-request

I recently went for a Kerala trip and saw this lamp:

[image]

So does these sculptures on the lamp mean something? Do they signify something?

Also this is my first question, so apologies if question is not clear.

Comment: In which temple did you see this?

Comment: It was a small temple in a village near Alleppey. I believe it was Shiva's temple

Comment: I think the lamp is designed as a tree and the creatures are merely for decoration.